# Is spark standalone scheduler or Yarn scheduler better for a Cloudera 5.4 hadoop cluster?

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, scheduler, hadoop-yarn

In regards to being able to run machine learning jobs with Spark. Which is a better choice the Yarn scheduler or the Spark Standalone scheduler?

Comment: It all depends, I do not see any significant difference but is there anything specific you are looking and comparing in both cluster managers?

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference when it comes to run the actual spark job.

Yarn/Mesos helps you to schedule resources if you have different spark applictions running and/or other components running in your cluster (which support Yarn/Mesos of course).

The Spark standalone cluster cannot manage resources. That is if you start a Spark application and it uses all the ressources, the second application will not find any resources left. That means you have to do this by yourself (e.g. adapting Spark config accordingly)